# Magento 2 - Admin Layout XML - Update Template and change block type for specific category

Tags: magento2, layout, admin-panel

What I thought to be an easy update, well at least in Magento 1, has turned into a huge adventure. Simply updating a template and a block type for a single category via the Magento admin, an out of box feature for Magento 1... Now I'm stumped. :(

Originally I tried the below:  Note: I used the blocktype of  `Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation` as it contained access to the current categories children and other logic I needed, why duplicate something that already exists right?  In the admin panel I am editing a category and have set the "Custom Layout Update" to:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/subcat-list.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Then I got the error: `Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1`

Why do you need to target a reference container inside of the Admin panel, and can't just reference the desired block? In my adventures, I believe I tried this exact xml inside module layout file and I remember it working as expected.

Common Magento, How do you reference a block nested two levels deep from the container without duplicating everything?

Let's start being crazy, begin by using methods that are supposedly deprecated by Magento. I then tried the following with visual success... Feels so dirty:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="category.products">
        <block name="product_list" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/subcat-list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Well, this worked but now I get an exception in the logs of: `Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The element 'category.products' already has a child with alias 'product_list' in /var/www/signatureneedle_magento/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611`

I know, because I'm redeclaring it Magento....   Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Am I crazy, or does this ability not exist anymore... or am I doing this completely wrong?   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Robert